# Calculate sum by grouping by column value in R

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I have a data frame with two columns, a `Ref_Date` column and a `Value` column. The date column contains 12 rows for each year, from 1988 until 2015. What I need to do is to group by the year only and summarize the `Value` column so that I can get only one row for each year containing the sum of all values for each of the 12 months of that year:

```
row.names   Ref_Date    Value
166483      1989/01     713
166484      1989/02     771
166485      1989/03     565
166486      1989/04     1248
166487      1989/05     1380
166488      1989/06     1118
166489      1989/07     1026
166490      1989/08     995
166491      1989/09     835
166492      1989/10     939
166493      1989/11     878
166494      1989/12     1075
166495      1990/01     878
166496      1990/02     563
166497      1990/03     773
166498      1990/04     1131
166499      1990/05     1562
166500      1990/06     1747
166501      1990/07     1258
166502      1990/08     791
```

Comment: That's a good question.

Comment: It is getting downvoted (didn't downvote yet, but have an irresistible urge to do so) because we would expect posting an image from a new user, not someone with your experience on the site. How are we supposed to reproduce this? By writing every single value by hand? Please follow the guidelines in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Probably because it doesn't demonstrate research effort and because the data is only presented as image (i.e. not reproducible).

Comment: @all of you, I have posted the data in plain text. Sorry about that,

Comment: This is really two questions - how do i extract just the year from a string, and how do I get the mean by group. Both of those have many duplicates on this site - i think that's the bigger issue for downvoters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(year = substr(Ref_Date, 1, 4)) %>%     # create the groups
  summarise(Value = sum(Value))

#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#
#  year Value
#1 1989 11543
#2 1990  8703
```

Or similarly with `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, sum(Value), by = .(year = substr(Ref_Date, 1, 4))]
#   year    V1
#1: 1989 11543
#2: 1990  8703
```

Or with base R

```
with(df, aggregate(Value ~ cbind(year = substr(Ref_Date, 1, 4)), FUN = sum))
#  year Value
#1 1989 11543
#2 1990  8703
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it, although it may be more helpful to beginners to separate the mutation statement into its own logic -- that is `mutate(year = substr(Ref_Date, 1, 4))` followed by `group_by(year)`

Comment: COuld you please write this statement again but without using pipes ?

Comment: @JFBeaulieu, I believe that would be a good exercise for you. I already spoon-fed you the code

Answer (score 1):

Another answer could be the following (by using `tapply`):

```
years <- 1988:2015 ## or first.year:last.year
sums <- tapply(df$Value, substr(df$Ref_Date, 1, 4)), sum)
new.df <- data.frame(years = years, sums = sums)
```

**EDIT:** Just a more general solution to avoid standard dates (but it's basically similar to the one posted above):

```
years <- substr(df$Ref_Date, 1, 4)
sums <- tapply(df$Value, years, sum)
new.df <- data.frame(years = unique(years), sum = sums)
```

Comment: It worked for me... Just needed to change the second line to: sums <- tapply(as.numeric(df$Value), substr(df$Ref_Date, 1, 4), sum)

Comment: Oh, I'm glad it did, I had no idea you had stored the values as strings. But It's OK in the end, I guess.

Comment: This basically @docendos solution. Should be a comment at best, but whatever.

Comment: As soon as docendo's answer was posted, the OP asked for a version without pipes and that's what I provided. I had no intention of answering in the first place, since I thought that answer was enough.

Comment: You can unpipe the `dplyr` solution, for example `summarise(group_by(df, year = substr(Ref_Date, 1, 4)), Value = sum(Value))`